# Resend HTTP header

Tags: c#, http, video-streaming

I have application. It send request to my proxy class. Proxy must to parse http header string (I done this) and resend it request to server to get a video.

At first, mediacomponent connect to proxy:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:2233/files/1.mp4");
videoPlayer.Source = uri;
Play();
```

Proxy get http header string

```
"GET /files/1.mp4 HTTP/1.1\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nPragma: getIfoFileURI.dlna.org\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514 WMFSDK/12.00.7601.17514\r\nGetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:2233\r\n\r\n"
```

I replase host:

```
"GET /files/1.mp4 HTTP/1.1\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nPragma: getIfoFileURI.dlna.org\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514 WMFSDK/12.00.7601.17514\r\nGetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1\r\nHost: myserver.ru\r\n\r\n"
```

Now proxy must get video from server. What must I do?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague and incomplete, and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: I just must to make a video streaming and caching. Proxy will save video in the filesystem and stream it from server to mediacomponent.

Comment: @user2155564 What are you using to send the request to the server? HttpClient? HttpRequest? Other?

Comment: @rhughes
 Request from media component to proxy
 var
uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:2233/files/.mp4");
Play();
I noob, I kno.

Comment: @user2155564 Thanks. Could you update your question with that code please?

Comment: @rhughes done, what's next?

Comment: @user2155564 Thanks. What is the video player that you are using?

Comment: Please, sorry for my small knowledge :С
    `public partial class VideoPlayer : UserControl
 public VideoPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
.......
            videoPlayer.Clock = null;
            videoPlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

When using .NET, you don't have to manually create the HTTP message itself. Instead, use the classes in the [System.Net.Http namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193585.aspx) to form and send an HTTP message and process the response.

For example, sending an HTTP GET message to a URL can be as simple as:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.foobar.com/");
var client = new HttpClient();
string body = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Note that this general approach will download the entire contents of the resource at the given URI. In your case, you may not want to wait for the whole video to download before you start playing/processing/storing it. In which case, you might want to use the `HttpClient.ReadAsStream()` method which will return a stream from which you can read until the stream closes.